# How to kill Java thread when it is finished?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, java-threads

First time I am working with threads in spring boot webapp and when I do debugging then I see thread names are increasing like Thread-1, Thread-2... for every call method so I thought that the program is not killing the thread but creating new thread for every call.

Here is my code:

```
public Advert saveAdvert(Advert advert) {
        Advert advertToSave = advertRepository.save(advert);

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                populateAdvertSearch(advertToSave);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OfficeNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OfficePropertyNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
        return advertToSave;
    }
```

Here `populateAdvertSearch()` is a void method. I just want to do that task independently from the main thread because it is very long and I do not want client to wait whole method so another independent thread will do this void method. But as I said I though that the program is not killing threads. How can I kill the thread or Should I kill explicitly (I am not sure maybe it is already killed after execution is done but then why Intellij IDEA debug showing thread names as increasing)

Comment: [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: Assuming the call to `populateAdvertSearch` is returning (whether normally or by throwing an exception), then your thread is eventually dying on its own. But you are creating a new thread every time `saveAdvert` is called. That's where the different thread names are coming from. If you want to _reuse_ threads, then look into `ExecutorService` (or see if Spring provides its own thread pool API).

Comment: Re, "I thought that the program is...creating new thread for every call." That's exactly what your `saveAdvert()` function does: It creates a new thread every time it is called.

Comment: Re, "so I thought that the program is not killing the thread..." Just because it creates new threads, that doesn't mean it isn't allowing them to die after they've done their work. If it was continually creating threads and _not_ letting them die, then your debugger would show the list of threads getting longer and longer until eventually your program ran out of memory, or the OS ran out of some other thread-related reource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After thread starts and `run()` method returns, that `Thread` will terminate and eventually be garbage collected. You see incrementing id numbers because you are starting new threads for each such action. So no explicit termination is required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The called method is not returning anything it is void method so is it still ok ? And when we going to production with big data, is this name increment a problem or is it just a feature of the IDEA ?

Comment: @abidinberkay It's not about IntelliJ. You're using [the constructor of thread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Runnable)) whose documentation says it "_has the same effect as Thread (null, task, gname), where gname is a newly generated name. Automatically generated names are of the form "Thread-"+n, where n is an integer._". The `n` is likely the ID of the thread, which is documented to be unique across all thread instances in the JVM. You're creating new threads; therefore, you get "incrementing names".

Comment: So this naming will it be a problem when we go to the production with big amount of data? And my called method is void and not returning anything so does it still killed ?

Comment: @abidinberkay The result of the method, whether `void`, an object, `null`, or an exception, is irrelevant. It's about whether the `run()` method returns at all, at least with regards to the thread terminating. As for the naming being a problem, it will not be a problem in and of itself. But it does indicate you're creating a new thread every time the `saveAdvert` method is called. Creating threads is expensive. And depending on the frequency this method is called, you could end up overwhelming your computer with thousands of threads. I would look into reusing threads with a thread pool.

Comment: @abidinberkay If you want to you can create the Threads using the `ExecutorService` which will allow you to customizes the thread names and some other configurations with which you can safely go to production. Find more about executor service [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

## Use [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html)

In a Web Application, creating Threads manually isn't the right way to go. This process is constful, and it's better to maintain a Pool of Threads.

Since you're using Spring Boot, everything you need is annotate the configuration class with [`@EnableAsync`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) and [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) would be configured for you under the hood. You can customize it via `application.properties` (for instance, specify the required min/max pool size).

And to tell that a certain method should be executed in a different Thread, you need to place annotation [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) on it (*note that this method should reside in a class managed by Spring, i.e. annotated with one of the stereotype annotations* `@Component`, `@Controller`, etc.).

```
@Async
public Advert saveAdvert(Advert advert) {
    Advert advertToSave = advertRepository.save(advert);

    try {
        populateAdvertSearch(advertToSave);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OfficeNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OfficePropertyNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return advertToSave;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a good idea to terminate a running thread from the outside, but if you want so, you can use `ExecutorService`.

Let's say you want to kill specific thread after 5 seconds;

```
if (executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
  // continue
} else {
  // force shutdown
  executor.shutdownNow();
}
```

Comment: The `executor.shutdownNow()` method does _not_ promise to "terminate running threads from the outside." It is only supposed to [_interrupt_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) the worker threads. If some client-supplied task function does respond to the interrupt either by a normal return or an exceptional return, then the interrupt will not terminate the worker that is running that task.